# Use props inside emotion's css string template

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm in the middle of migrating my design system from styled-components to emotion.

In SC, The following syntax is considered valid:

```js
export interface AvatarProps {
  // ...
  shape: AvatarShape;
  size: AvatarSize;
}

const borderRadiusByShape = css<Pick<AvatarProps, "shape" | "size">>`
  border-radius: ${(props) => {
    return match(props.shape)
      .with("circle", () => `${props.size}px`)
      .with("square", () => "0px")
      ...
      .exhaustive();
  }}
`;

const StyledAvatar = styled.div<AvatarProps>`
  /* ... */
  ${borderRadiusByShape};
`;
```

This pattern allows me to reuse my `borderRadius` across multiple `styled.[x]` declarations.

Looking at emotion's `css` function, it looks like emotion doesn't support that syntax. Is there any workaround that won't require me to wrap this functionality with a new component?

Answer (score 0):

Afer a bit of digging, it turns out I can extract the props from `css` and create a function that accept these props and return the corresponding CSS:

```js
export interface AvatarProps {
  // ...
  shape: AvatarShape;
  size: AvatarSize;
}

const borderRadiusByShape = (props: Pick<AvatarProps, "shape" | "size">) => css`
  border-radius: ${match(props.shape)
    .with("circle", () => `${props.size}px`)
    .with("square", () => "0px")
    /* ... */
    .exhaustive()};
`;

const StyledAvatar = styled.div<AvatarProps>`
  /* ... */
  ${borderRadiusByShape};
`;
```